# How can I make this sub query more efficient?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been learning more about making my sql queries more efficient, but I don't know if I'm doing this query properly.

I'm trying to find a set in one group, but not the other group. This is the original query which works:

```
SELECT
 cNumber
FROM
  [dataset.table]
WHERE
  DATE(date) >= '2016-01-01'
  AND cNumber NOT IN (
    SELECT
     cNumber
    FROM
     [dataset.table]
    WHERE
     date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),-5, "QUARTER")
     AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "QUARTER"))
GROUP BY
 1
```

When I change my query to the one below, I get a larger number of results:

```
SELECT
 cNumber
FROM
 dataset.table
WHERE
 DATE(date) >= '2016-01-01'
 AND date NOT BETWEEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), -5, "QUARTER")
 AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "QUARTER")
GROUP BY
 1
```

For this type of query, do I need to include a `NOT IN` subquery or should I could I just use the second query?

I think I am confused in the second query by trying to include the `AND orderCreationDate NOT BETWEEN`. I thought that since I'm doing a subquery on the same table, that I would be able to wrap it up into one query.

Comment: are you using BigQuery or something else?

Comment: I'm using BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for BigQuery (Legacy SQL) try below

```
SELECT cNumber
FROM [dataset.table]
GROUP BY cNumber
HAVING MAX(DATE(date)) >= '2016-01-01' 
AND SUM(CASE 
    WHEN DATE(date) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -5, "QUARTER")) 
    AND  DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "QUARTER"))
    THEN 1 ELSE 0
  END) = 0
```

Comment: Could explain why this query works or what the difference is? I haven't seem a sum with a case statement before.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may do what you want:

```
SELECT cNumber
FROM [dataset.table]
GROUP BY cnumber
HAVING MAX(DATE(date)) >= '2016-01-01' AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), -5, "QUARTER") AND
                                  DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, "QUARTER"))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) = 0;
```

That is, choose `cnumber`s that have a record sometime since 2016-01-01 and don't have one in the other period specified.

Whether this is faster or not, I do not know.  You have to try it out.

Comment: @chipoglesby . . . This isn't "also".  This was posted 20 minutes before the other answer, which is essentially the same.

Comment: From what I understand - it just doesn't work at all - for BigQuery at least!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . If the original query works this one should.  The OP is clearly not using legacy SQL.

Comment: the trick is  - original does not! ;o) original will not work in any Standard or Legacy

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I understand what you are saying and at least one reason why, but the OP clearly says:  "This is the original query which works".  People sometimes make changes to their queries when they post them here.